# How to create a secure C# application that connects to a Laravel web app on Azure to fetch MySql database

Tags: c#, php, mysql, laravel, azure

I have an **Azure** web application with **Laravel 5.7.6**

The web application should fetch a **MySql** database hosted on Azure whenever asked from a C# application (**Unity**)

Given that:

- The C# application is used in Unity context (so possibly vulnerable);
- There won't be an auth system involved, but just exchange of information;

**How to create a secure connection from the C# application to the PHP one? In particular, how to encrypt (if necessary) connection data in C#? Is necessary to also encrypt the communication between the 2 apps?**

Comment: If no auth system is involved, is there a huge point in securing it? To secure communications at the transport level, you should use SSL (https://~~~~).

Comment: Hi @John, thank you for your answer. This application I'm working on should be very scalable. That's why I was asking about security from the beginning, I don't want to find myself redoing the whole work when I have xxxx users because the code is weak. This said the data provided from the Azure application regards mostly products, so you think encryption of this data would be useless?

Comment: I think it may be useless because of this: You've said that there's no authentication involved - this means that either there's some kind of key hard-coded into your application, or that there's no key at all. If it's hard-coded, then an attacker could extract it, defeating the point of securing it. If there's no key, then anyone can request the data. If you simply want transport-level security, then SSL would work, but if anyone can request the data without being verified, then I'm not 100% sure what the value is, except that you could add authentication later and keep the same SSL layer.

Comment: @John I see. thank you very much for your answer and explanation. What about the credentials in the c# code? How can I keep them safe?